# Efficiently check if exactly 2 days passed from given datetime in my case

Tags: php

I have following code that add 2 days to a given date.

```
$myDate = 2018-07-28 11:00:00; // the date is picked from db
$penaltyDays = 2;
$date1 = new DateTime($myDate);
$date1->add(new DateInterval("P{$penaltyDays}D")); // add N days
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $date1->diff($now); // get difference
$days = $interval->d; // difference in days
```

I want value of $days must be 0 after passing exactly 48 hours. If 3 days are passed the value of $days should be -1.
I will also appreciate if someone tell me efficient/proper way to get the result.

Comment: So from `2018-07-28 11:00:00` you want a new date that is `2018-07-30 11:00:00`? Should that be the output or what is the expected output? Are you really storing string dates in the database? Why not Unix? What do you mean by efficiently? Fastest code, fewest line, something else?

Comment: Currently if 25 hour are passed the value of `$days` is zero, I want if whole 48 hours are passed the value of `$days` should be zero. Yes, I am storing the value of  `$myDate` in database. By efficiently mean to put less burden on server in terms of RAM and CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an efficient code according to your specification then I would rather use strtotime than DateTime.
This code checks if the current time is larger than the database time + two (or three) days in seconds.

```
$myDate = "2018-07-28 11:00:00"; 
$unix = strtotime($myDate);

if(time() > ($unix + 86400*3)){
    $days = -1;
}else if(time() > ($unix + 86400*2)){
    $days = 0;
}else{
    $days = "something else";
}

Echo $days;
```

https://3v4l.org/d6Q15

Comment: thank you @Andreas, just add on more thing in else block to echo how many days are left till '($unix + 86400*2)'

Comment: Yes, but `ceil` instead of `floor` upvote by question if possible.